# Can a Rails app be deployed without using Heroku Toolbelt? If so, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I want to deploy rails app without using Heroku ToolBelt. Is it possible? If so, how? I'm only allowed to use Heroku dashboard; I'm not allowed to use any other cloud service :(

I have to run PostgreSQL commands, adding add-ons and setting configuration variables and possibly other tasks for which we have Heroku Toolbelt to deploy a application in production environment.

Error:

```
user@xx ~/Desktop/github/blog (master)
$ git push git@heroku.com:herokugui.git master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't want to use Heroku Toolbelt. That's why I am using Git commands to deploy code on Heroku. I am not able to push code to Heroku using Git commands. Is it possible to do this task without the toolbelt?

Another question I have is: is there any way to run PostgreSQL commands on Heroku GUI? If so, how?

Comment: which problem have you with heroku toolbelt? just setup keys properly

Comment: I had logged ticket to heroku support team for this. I am not able to use heroku toolbelt because of firewall protection which is restricting to "api.heroku.com" to make a connection. That's why I need alternative to deploy rails app without using heroku tool belt. Please suggest me any solution @МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: the firewall is in your control?

Comment: No, IT team is looking for authorizing api.heroku.com, But I want deploy app on heroku without heroku toolbelt?@МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: Just yet question, from what did you know that api.heroku.com is banned?

Comment: Actually, I don't know about this. I have to use my company system where I am working. They have blocked so many sites for security purposes.@МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: but why are you sure that the heroku.com was blocked?

Comment: This is confirmed by security Team.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not easy (as with Heroku toolbelt), but it's possible. It involves hanging around your Heroku dashboard at least, so make sure you can access it.

First off, you need a key. If you're on a Linux machine (as me), then in your **home directory** you should have a folder named `.ssh` (it may be hidden, hit `Ctrl+H` to reveal, again, if Linux) and a file `id_rsa.pub` in there. If not, you need to generate your SSH key first.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

That will prompt you for a folder, default is fine, just hit `Enter`, then **enter the passphrase** (twice) to protect your key from being accessed by anyone else on your computer: without a passphrase it's unencrypted and free for anyone to take and use from that machine.

Once that is done, locate your public key file: `id_rsa.pub`. **Note**: not `id_rsa`, it's a private key, you may not want to give it to anyone, it's much like your future Heroku password, except for it's insanely large for a password. Open `id_rsa.pub`, you should see stuff like:

```
ssh-rsa aWhOLELotofUnreadABLEGibbERishWHiCHiSactUALLyYourPubLIcKeY...
```

You need to enter that line into your account settings in Heroku dashboard, under **SSH Keys**. You can find more info on keys [here, in Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys). Make sure Heroku actually recognizes you by issuing this:

```
ssh -v git@heroku.com
```

It should state you're authenticated.

Now for the `git` address. I assume you know your way around `git`, so I'll keep it short: you'll need to derive your repository address from your app name. Heroku usually generates weird (yet somewhat poetic) names like `falling-wind-1624` or `shielded-fjord-1858`. I'll take the first one as an example, this is how you add its address as a git remote:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:falling-wind-1624.git
```

I'll explain a bit of it below. So what the toolbelt does here, is to use your app name only, it just builds the URL the same way by adding a path to Heroku server. Once that's done, you should be able to push your code:

```
git push heroku master
```

I've named a Heroku remote `heroku`, above, that's why I'm using `heroku` name here, you can name it whatever you want and use this afterwards. Once you've pushed the code, the rest is up to you.

Comment: Great little guide, thanks. Minor difference I encountered were that I had to do `git push heroku master` for the last step, and I looked up the remote address from the Settings tab in the interface.

Comment: @AsfandYarQazi actually, yes, they've added it to the dashboard quite a while ago. And I edited the last command to include the branch name, since letting `git` guess the remote branch requies some insight into `git`.