# Heroku Without Toolbelt On Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, toolbelt

Would like to be able to push to, and clone from, Heroku without the toolbelt.

I've got Win10x64, Rails 2.4.4, Ruby 2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to link to Heroku using [`ssh`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key):

1. You need to download & install [`git`](http://git-scm.com)
2. You need to generate your SSH key
3. You need to "link" your Heroku app to your computer's SSH key
4. You should then be able to `push`/`clone` from Heroku

--

This answer helped get it working:
https://serverfault.com/a/198709/241166

You have to set the `HOME` path of your `ssh` before performing `ssh-keygen -t rsa` (this actually doesn't seem to be the case; you *should* be able to browse to the required output folder & run `ssh-keygen -t rsa`):

[image: SSH Keygen]

`ssh` has its keys in `c:/Users/[username]/.ssh` by default.

This will set the `.pub` file, which you'll be able to open using a text editor (`notepad` will do):

You then need to copy the contents of the generated `.pub` file to Heroku's `Account Settings` option:

[image]

[image]

If you need to remove `Heroku` from `known_hosts`, [you'll want to use](https://serverfault.com/a/182060/241166):

```
ssh-keygen -H -F heroku.com

ssh-keygen -R heroku.com
```

--

Next, you need to [authenticate with Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101008/can-a-rails-app-be-deployed-without-using-heroku-toolbelt-if-so-how).

```
ssh -v git@heroku.com
```

This should then allow you to connect via SSH to Heroku *from that system*.
It may say a permission denied error - you should be able to ignore that, `cd` to the folder where the `git` repo is stored, and perform `push` / `commit`:

[image]

That's how to connect via SSH to Heroku on Windows :)